# how to run parallel test scripts with multiple browsers by selenium web-driver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, selenium-grid

I have tried the following code, but it's not working.
I am trying to run it on multiple browsers parallel.
I have used Testng too.but when I execute the below lines of code, it will execute on one browser like (firefox) and run all code, then it will open chrome browser and run all code.

But my requirement is to run those 3 browses at the same time(Simultaneously ).

```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="tests">
  <test name="Test1">
  <parameter name="browser" value="Firefox"/>
     <classes>
      <class name="parallel_script.Demo_parallel_script"/>
    </classes>
  </test> 
  <test name="Test2">
  <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/>
    <classes>
      <class name="parallel_script.Demo_parallel_script"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
  <test name="Test3">
  <parameter name="browser" value="IE"/>
     <classes>
      <class name="parallel_script.Demo_parallel_script"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

```

```

```
public class Demo_parallel_script {
    private WebDriver driver;
    String baseURL = "http://www.google.com/";
    @Parameters({ "browser" })
    @Test
    public void openBrowser(String browser) {
        try {
            if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Firefox")) {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","D:\\selenium driver\\geckodriver.exe");
                driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            } else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\selenium driver\\chromedriver.exe");
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
            } else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("IE")) {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "D:\\selenium driver\\IEDriverServer.exe");
                driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
            }
        } catch (WebDriverException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        driver.navigate().to(baseURL);
        String title_name=driver.getTitle();
        System.out.println(title_name);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='lst-ib']")).sendKeys("selenium");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@type='submit'])[1]")).click();
    }}
```

```

Comment: Can you please let us know what version of TestNG are you using ?

Comment: ```i am using maven project:-```
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>parallel_selenium_script</groupId>
  <artifactId>parallel_selenium_script</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
 <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>

 <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin=3.3</artifactId>

 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin=1.6</artifactId>
  
<artifactId>selenium-java=3.4.0</artifactId>
<artifactId>poi-ooxml=3.15</artifactId>
<artifactId>testng=6.11</artifactId>
<artifactId>selenium-java = 3.7.1</artifactId>```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add the complete contents of your `<dependencies>` tag from your pom file ?

Answer (score 0):

Set **threa-count** attribute value to **3** for the suite tag as given below to run all tests in parallel.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="tests" thread-count="3">
  <test name="Test1">
  <parameter name="browser" value="Firefox"/>
     <classes>
      <class name="parallel_script.Demo_parallel_script"/>
    </classes>
  </test> 
  <test name="Test2">
  <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/>
    <classes>
      <class name="parallel_script.Demo_parallel_script"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
  <test name="Test3">
  <parameter name="browser" value="IE"/>
     <classes>
      <class name="parallel_script.Demo_parallel_script"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Comment: thanks for your response, this time I am using maven project. my given code was working on a simple java project. But same code not working on maven project.please, i need your suggestions on this. actually, i need a code for my maven project.